# Изменение картинки по клику

Tags: html, javascript, css

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на картинку она менялась, а точнее дополнялась ее отдельная часть?

Answer (score 1):

С помощью JS замените значение свойства src у картинки на другое, например.

Хотя это не единственный способ сделать сие =)

Можно сделать чуть хитрее, если надо просто расширить картинку, - картинку в фон, размеры фиксированные, overflow:hidden. Сначала размер один - видна часть картинки. Потом с помощью JS меняется на другой, больший - скрытая часть картинки проявляется.

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="document.getElementById('id_картинки').src = 'адрес_новой';"
```

Вроде так, не тестил

Comment: Это вставлять в тег img  
<img src="123" onclick="....">

Comment: Тогда уж this.src = 'адрес'; , если в картинку.